# Running multiple devices off a single SMPS

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, surge-protection

**Disclaimer: I am a DIYer/Hobbyist**

I have a few 12 V devices, each with their own 'wall-wart'. I would like to keep everything a bit more tidy, by having all of the following devices connected to a single power source:

- Cisco Managed Switch - 12 V @ 1 A
- Cisco Unmanaged Switch - 12 V @ 1 A
- Mini PC server - 12 V @ 3 A
- Mini PC firewall router - 12 V @2 A

The specs above are taken from each of the wall-wart's DC output rating. I'm selecting a MeanWell 12 V 15 A SMPS to allow for some headroom and expansion.

Now I know that this type of question has been asked before, but I have a friend who advised me against this, saying that if one of the connected devices suddenly goes down (like one of Mini PCs crashes and powers off), it may send a surge of current through to the other connected devices and cause irreparable damage.

I would just like to know if there is any truth to this please?

Comment: It may not be technically sensible (or EMC legal) to common the DC supplies to all these devices either.

Comment: Do you really want a device rated for 1A supply to be connected to a 15A supply? If the original power cables use wires rated for 1A, and there is a short circuit in a device, what do you think happens to the device or 1A cables? Will the power supply shut down, or will the cables melt and burn or vapourize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see how one device going down  would "send a surge of current through to the other connected devices" provided the SMPS is well designed with adequate output regulation. However if one device goes down as a short circuit the SMPS should shut down (for mutual protection) and the other devices will lose power as well. It shouldn't do them any harm, but you will, of course, lose all their functions.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario your friend described is very unlikely with any reasonable quality power supply. Current does not magically "surge" through other devices if one of the devices turns off.

If one of the devices fails in a way that causes a short-circuit across the supply, it will trigger the supply's overcurrent limit (or blow a fuse) and turn the supply off, which will turn off all of your devices. If your power supply fails, this will also obviously cause all the devices to turn off. If you're ok with the power supply being a single point of failure for all of those devices, that's fine. If not, you'll probably want separate supplies.

The main concern here is that you're attaching a very high current supply to devices that expect to draw a much lower current. While this won't make any difference in terms of operation - the devices will draw whatever current they need - the devices may be designed with safety margins that expect the maximum supply current in a fault scenario (e.g. short circuit) to be only a few amps. As such, they may not be designed to fail safely if you attach a power supply that is capable of sourcing several times more short-circuit current than the intended supply could.

This can go horribly wrong when your replacement supply's normal operating current exceeds the maximum short circuit current of the original supply. The cabling and PCB traces are designed to carry a certain amount of current without overheating and catching fire or causing injury. This limit is selected based on the protections that are present in the system. If the power supply that comes with the device is incapable of sourcing more than 3A, then the designer might rate the cabling and connectors and PCB traces for 5A. If an overcurrent event occurs, the device and cables do not overheat. However, if you then attach a supply capable of supplying 15A continuously (and much more current transiently) and an overcurrent event occurs, you now potentially have many times the rated current flowing through the cables and device. Since power through a fixed resistance conductor is proportionate to the square of the current, i.e. \$P=I^2R\$, a 15A overcurrent fault represents 25 times as much power dissipation than a 3A overcurrent fault. This can cause the cabling to become incredibly hot, causing injury or fire.

Comment: Are you sure? Do you know happens to output voltage when suddenly one device is unplugged so there is a load step of 1A? Some supplies react fast, some react slowly, which is why ATX supplies tend to turn off due to overvoltage when you disconnect the last 12V load as there might be sudden overvoltage.

Comment: @Justme You're correct that there's a possibility for regulation transients if there is excessive dI/dt, but I'd be very confident that a Meanwell SMPS could tolerate shedding one fifth of its rated load without presenting a damaging voltage on its outputs.

Comment: Just because it's known brand power supply, it does not mean you can assume something without knowing the model and reading the data sheet. But yes, that would be the initial, unconfirmed assumption.

Comment: To mitigate this short circuit fire risk you can of course add a fuse in series with each device.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is dead wrong.

First, think of an ATX PSU: The 12V rail is used by a lot of sub systems such as GPU (has its own DC-DC converter), CPU (has its own DC-DC converter and fan driver), case fans, etc.

Now ask this question yourself: Does any other sub system get damaged when one of the sub systems gets lighter or even stops drawing current (e.g. one of the case fans stopped by the MoBo)?

---

If the load of an SMPS drops to zero from full load then the output voltage may want to rise, This might be the phenomenon that your friend talks about. But this rise won't be that high to damage other loads. And also, the power supply you are about to buy (and other similar ones) are designed to deliver stable output voltage at step load changes (e.g. 0 to 100% and vice versa).

So no, there won't be such problems as long as you keep the total load within the PSU's spec.

Comment: How do you know how the unmentioned power supply handles a load step? Besides, ATX supplies come with specification, and specifications require the rate of load step must be 1.0A/us.

Comment: @Justme you're right. For a moment I thought (I don't know why) the OP selected an industrial grade PSU. Editing my answer. Thanks for pointing out.